# Write a function in PHP that can extract all text within a given Html string and Tag

Tags: php

I want to write a function in php which can extract all the text withing given html string and tag.

something like this:

**function signature**

```
function HTMLTextExtrator(htmlString, tagName)
return type : string
```

**Example:**

```
$string=<body><div>this is a <p>text</p> to be extracted</div></body>    
echo  HTMLTextExtrator($string,p); // output: text    
echo  HTMLTextExtrator($string,div); // output: this is a <p>text</p> to be extracted    
echo  HTMLTextExtrator($string,body); // output:<div>this is a <p>text</p> to be extracted</div>
```

If anyone know what code can be inside the function to execute this....thanx

Comment: you can try to use it http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this function to see if it gives you what you want

```
<?php

/**
 *
 * @get text between tags
 *
 * @param string $tag The tag name
 *
 * @param string $html The XML or XHTML string
 *
 * @param int $strict Whether to use strict mode
 *
 * @return array
 *
 */
function getTextBetweenTags($tag, $html, $strict=0)
{
    /*** a new dom object ***/
    $dom = new domDocument;

    /*** load the html into the object ***/
    if($strict==1)
    {
        $dom->loadXML($html);
    }
    else
    {
        $dom->loadHTML($html);
    }

    /*** discard white space ***/
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

    /*** the tag by its tag name ***/
    $content = $dom->getElementsByTagname($tag);

    /*** the array to return ***/
    $out = array();
    foreach ($content as $item)
    {
        /*** add node value to the out array ***/
        $out[] = $item->nodeValue;
    }
    /*** return the results ***/
    return $out;
}
?>
```

A sample usage scenario:

```
<?php

$xhtml = '<html>
<body>
<para>This is a paragraph</para>
<para>This is another paragraph</para>
</body>
</html>';

$content2 = getTextBetweenTags('para', $xhtml, 1);
foreach( $content2 as $item )
{
    echo $item.'<br />';
}
?>
```

Comment: Modify the function and it will include the tags you specify. What you have above should be of great assistance to your work I believe

Comment: If you will find it hard to tweak then you can simply use PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser from http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 0):

Use `strip_tags()` for this. But the passed tag will not be stripped, rest will be stripped.

```
echo strip_tags('<p>hello</p> <div>World</div>', '<p></p>');
```

The output will be - `<p>hello</p> World`

Comment: it is only showing the `hello World` in the output without any tags

Comment: why it is not showing on my localhost then?? i wrote the same code but no success

Comment: check for the tags. they have to be same.

Comment: if you output to browser and echo it Browser will not show you tags.

Comment: @sgtBOSE it does not produce same out as OP wants